# Flutter ListView.builder within a TabBarView throws hitTest error

Tags: flutter

I have a screen with three tabs. My third tab should have widgets built depending on data received. So I have the following class that contains my ListView.builder for that specific tab.

```
class ThirdFormEdit extends StatelessWidget {
  ThirdFormEdit({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  Map<dynamic,dynamic> _values = new Map();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final FormsInheritedWidgetState state = FormsInheritedWidget.of(context,true);
    _values = state.editableAllValues["ThirdForm"];

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _values.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Text("Test",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black));
      }
    );
  }
}
```

And this class is called as a child of a TabBarView here:

```
DefaultTabController(
    length: 3,
    child: Scaffold(
    body: TabBarView(
        children: <Widget>[
        SingleChildScrollView(child: FirstFormEdit(title: "Edit First Form",),),
        Text("Second Form"),
        SingleChildScrollView(child: ThirdFormEdit(title: "Edit First Form",),),
        ],
    ),
    ),
);
```

When I open the tab, I get the following errors:

```
I/flutter (22554): Another exception was thrown: Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
I/flutter (22554): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#8e25e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (22554): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#8e25e NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (22554): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIgnorePointer#b8d17 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (22554): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#fcf71 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (22554): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#14047 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (22554): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#3ea95 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (22554): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#47980 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (22554): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderScrollSemantics#d5f2c relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (22554): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#bff38 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (22554): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#cb5c4 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (22554): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#bfb82 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (22554): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderSingleChildViewport#19173 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (22554): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIgnorePointer#2c868 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (22554): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#7623a NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (22554): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#c443d NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (22554): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#12cd3 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (22554): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#8701f NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (22554): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderScrollSemantics#1935e NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (22554): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#684e0 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (22554): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#0fa83 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (22554): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#7440e NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (22554): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#04e1a NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (22554): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 549 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
I/flutter (22554): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIndexedSemantics#c8dd5 NEEDS-PAINTI/flutter (22554): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 549 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
E/flutter (22554): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: Cannot hit test a render box with no size.
E/flutter (22554): The hitTest() method was called on this RenderBox: RenderIndexedSemantics#c8dd5 NEEDS-PAINT:
E/flutter (22554):   needs compositing
E/flutter (22554):   creator: IndexedSemantics ← NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification> ← KeepAlive ← AutomaticKeepAlive ← KeyedSubtree-[Key <[<2>]>] ← SliverFillViewport ← Viewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#2927f] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#8660e] ← ⋯
E/flutter (22554):   parentData: index=2; layoutOffset=720.0
E/flutter (22554):   constraints: BoxConstraints(w=360.0, h=552.0)
E/flutter (22554):   semantic boundary
E/flutter (22554):   size: MISSING
E/flutter (22554):   index: 2
E/flutter (22554): Although this node is not marked as needing layout, its size is not set.
E/flutter (22554): A RenderBox object must have an explicit size before it can be hit-tested. Make sure that the RenderBox in question sets its size during layout.
E/flutter (22554): #0      RenderBox.hitTest.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2119:9)
E/flutter (22554): #1      RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2134:6)
E/flutter (22554): #2      _RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor&RenderSliver&ContainerRenderObjectMixin&RenderSliverHelpers.hitTestBoxChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver.dart:1636:22)
E/flutter (22554): #3      BoxHitTestResult.addWithRawTransform (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:797:31)
E/flutter (22554): #4      BoxHitTestResult.addWithPaintOffset (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:754:12)
E/flutter (22554): #5      _RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor&RenderSliver&ContainerRenderObjectMixin&RenderSliverHelpers.hitTestBoxChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver.dart:1632:19)
E/flutter (22554): #6      RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:564:11)
E/flutter (22554): #7      RenderSliver.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver.dart:1279:11)
E/flutter (22554): #8      RenderViewportBase.hitTestChildren.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:585:24)
E/flutter (22554): #9      BoxHitTestResult.addWithRawTransform (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:797:31)
E/flutter (22554): #10     BoxHitTestResult.addWithPaintTransform (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:725:12)
E/flutter (22554): #11     RenderViewportBase.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:581:33)
E/flutter (22554): #12     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2136:11)
E/flutter (22554): #13     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:114:19)
E/flutter (22554): #14     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2136:11)
E/flutter (22554): #15     RenderIgnorePointer.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2972:37)
E/flutter (22554): #16     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:114:19)
E/flutter (22554): #17     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2136:11)
E/flutter (22554): #18     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:114:19)
E/flutter (22554): #19     RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:161:19)
E/flutter (22554): #20     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:114:19)
E/flutter (22554): #21     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2136:11)
E/flutter (22554): #22     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:114:19)
E/flutter (22554): #23     RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:161:19)
E/flutter (22554): #24     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:114:19)
E/flutter (22554): #25     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2136:11)
E/flutter (22554): #26     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:114:19)
E/flutter (22554): #27     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2136:11)
E/flutter (22554): #28     _RenderProxyBox&
```

I've tried putting the ListView.builder() inside a SizedBox but it didn't work. I understand the error is related to the size of the widget, but I don't know how to exactly solve it.

Answer (score 3):

After a few hours of searching I found the solution. In order for the ListView to work, I had to do what [Olaf Schlüter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11358843/olaf-schl%c3%bcter) said (Removing the `SingleChildScrollView`as the parnet of my widget) plus adding the `shrinkWrap` property to my ListView with the value true.

One more problem I encountered is that the ListView is then no longer scroll-able. The solution again, was to add the `physics` property to the ListView with the value `BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics())`.

Comment: Amine, you need to add `ClampingScrollPhysics()`, not `BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics())` while keeping the `SingleChildScrollView`

Answer (score 2):

Remove the SingleChildScrollView as a parent of the ListView. ListView scrolls by itself. The TabBarView will provide the size of the viewport to the ListView.